# Access parent function properties Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript class like this

```
function Palette() {

  this.selectedItem = "";

  this.addBox = function() {
    // Different approach, create a fake box
    b = $("<div id='box-palette' class='box'>Box</div>");
    b.insertBefore('#cont');

    b.mousedown(function() {
        this.selectedItem = "box"; // Here I want to access Palette#selectedItem
        console.log(Palette);
    });
  }
}
```

How can I access the property of the class in the function I want to pass to jQuery?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jquery]+oop+event+handler+context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is tagged with jQuery use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass the parent context to the callback method

```
function Palette() {

    this.selectedItem = "";

    this.addBox = function () {
        // Different approach, create a fake box
        b = $("<div id='box-palette' class='box'>Box</div>");
        b.insertBefore('#cont');

        b.mousedown($.proxy(function () {
            this.selectedItem = "box"; // Here I want to access Palette#selectedItem
            console.log(Palette);
        }, this));
    }
}
```

*Note: [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) was not used because of [lack IE<9 support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#compat-desktop)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it would be great if you could let me know the use of bind() in this context also. I am accepting the answer, thanks!

Comment: @jaibatrik both are used to pass a custom context to a function... `bind()` is a native extension to `Function.prototype` - but it is supported only in newer versions of browsers